# I cannot find why my list is not as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
Ss = [0.806, 0.773, 1.1014, 0.786, 1.095, 0.803, 
      0.806, 0.785, 1.014, 0.586, 0.955, 1.088, 
      0.752, 1.010, 1.246, 0.879, 1.284]
S1 = [0.228, 0.220, 0.280, 0.231, 0.297, 0.226,
      0.228, 0.231, 0.280, 0.174, 0.264, 0.295, 
      0.217, 0.279, 0.338, 0.247, 0.351]
Fs = [1.200, 1.200, 1.094, 1.200, 0.800, 1.200, 
      1.200, 1.200, 1.094, 1.266, 1.118, 1.065, 
      1.200, 1.096, 1.200, 0.800, 0.900]
F1 = [1.500, 1.500, 2.040, 1.500, 0.800, 1.500,
      1.500, 1.500, 2.040, 1.500, 2.072, 2.010, 
      1.500, 2.042, 1.500, 0.800, 0.800]

SDS = []                # Short Term Design Acceleration Constant (Dimensionless)
SD1 = []                # 1 second Period Design Acceleration Constant (Dimensionless)

for i in range(len(F1)):
    SDS.append(Ss[i]*Fs[i])
for i in range(len(F1)):
    SD1.append(S1[i]*F1[i])
```

I am using Anaconda - Spyder. SDS and SD1 lists are not demonstrated as a variable. I could not find my mistake. I also try to open in Python IDLE, but it is still giving the same mistake. If there is any missing punctuation, please say it.

Comment: [Seems to run fine](https://repl.it/repls/CapitalAdeptInternalcommand).

Comment: I don't quite understand...where's the problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by SDS and SD1 not being demonstrated as a variable? Can you explain a bit more in depth? If you are getting any errors, kindly add them into your question too.

Comment: Works here. I'm guessing some sort of hidden character in the mix. Or encoding issues. What OS and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself creates the two lists, `SDS` and `SD1` (i.e. the issue is not with the Python code). If you're trying to inspect these variables in [Spyder's Variable Explorer](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/variableexplorer.html) (which you didn't state, but I assume here), and you can not find them, make sure

- the code is executed in Spyder's console,
- the [Variable Explorer's auto-refresh is enabled](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4154#issuecomment-298342374),
- the Variable Explorer is actually opened in the GUI.

Honestly, I'm not a Spyder user, so I may be missing something.

---

P.S.: you could make the for loops more pythonic by iterating using `zip` (including an example for the first loop). *You can name `ss_element` and `fs_element` however you like.*

```py
for ss_element, fs_element in zip(Ss, Fs):
    SDS.append(ss_element * fs_element)
```

Or even better, list comprehension.

```py
SDS = [ss_element * fs_element for ss_element, fs_element in zip(Ss, Fs)
```

But the most pythonic way would be to use a library which enables clean element-wise operations, like `numpy`.

```py
import numpy as np

Ss = np.array([0.806, 0.773, 1.1014, 0.786, 1.095, 0.803, 
               0.806, 0.785, 1.014, 0.586, 0.955, 1.088, 
               0.752, 1.010, 1.246, 0.879, 1.284])
Fs = np.array([1.200, 1.200, 1.094, 1.200, 0.800, 1.200, 
               1.200, 1.200, 1.094, 1.266, 1.118, 1.065, 
               1.200, 1.096, 1.200, 0.800, 0.900])

SDS = Ss * Fs
```

Comment: When I made SDS as SdS and SD1 as Sd1, the mistake is completely removed. Could the mistake be reasoned from list names?

Comment: Aha! Nice finding! It must be that Spyder handles global variables (i.e. variables with all capital letters) differently. See [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/614) and [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1378) GitHub issues.